# How do I Loop Through Directories with a Batch File when they have spaces in the path?

Tags: batch-file

I've started on a batch file that Window's **`Task Scheduler`** can run every Friday to clean up by deleting file bloat. I think my next step is to abstract it into a for loop that can be fed a list of directories, bonus points if I can read that list from an external file as well. (Mainly for security, the manager wants to make sure only they can change the list, but each employee should be able to run it locally.)

```
::      C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Temp
::      C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\PacCache
::      C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2023\CollaborationCache
::      C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2023\CefCache
::      C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2023\Journals

:: Delete all files
 del /s /q "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\DeletedWeeklyOnFriday\*.*"

:: Delete all folders
 for /d %%p in ("C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\DeletedWeeklyOnFriday\*.*") do rmdir "%%p" /s /q

exit
```

When I try to loop through the list of files it's breaking on the spaces

```
@echo OFF
FOR %%x IN (
    1
    2
    3
Temp
Autodesk\Revit\PacCache
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2020\CollaborationCache
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2020\CefCache
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2020\Journals
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2022\CollaborationCache
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2022\CefCache
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2022\Journals
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2023\CollaborationCache
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2023\CefCache
Autodesk\Revit\Autodesk Revit 2023\Journals
    ) DO ECHO %%x
PAUSE
```

I've tried back ticks, double quotes and percent signs to escape them, but no luck yet
[image]

Comment: quote each path: `for %%a in ("one" "two three" "four five six") do echo %%a`

Comment: I've tried double quotes, it does keep it all on one line, but then the quotes are part of it which isn't part of the path

Comment: `... echo %%~a` to remove the quotes.

Comment: ok, thank you. I can at least make progress now.

Comment: @Stephan
that worked out really well, the only thing I have left is to see if I can move the list of paths to an external file

Comment: Of course, you can. Iterate over the file instead of a bunch of strings: `for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do echo %%a` (no need for quotes in this case)